# Webpack global JS error handler and "Script error"

Tags: javascript, webpack, error-handling, single-page-application

I have a react project build with Webpack. There is an error (most likely a missing JS feature, but it's just a guess), that only reveals itself in "fetch as Google", whatever browser/JS engine they're using in this tool.

Obviously I don't have a console or other means to get an error, other than `window.onerror` or `window.addEventListener('error')`. I tried adding these handlers (I assume they're interchangeable) both as external `<script>` above main bundle or directly inside `index.js` as first import.

These handlers capture an error, but the error message is very generic "Script error" and other params, such as line number, are 0. I googled this and every solution suggests that errors like this happen when 3rd party scripts are loaded w/o CORS, but thing is there are no 3rd party scripts on my page, there is only webpack bundle. I guess it's somehow related to the way webpack separates modules... when I trigger the error inside the main component, where handlers are imported, the error message is displayed correctly.

I have no clue which module causes this error so I can't attach the handlers properly (I read this is most likely caused by new ESnext features, so I tried adding a number of shims, again both inside the bundle or as external script above main bundle, but this didn't help).

Is there a way to bypass that 'Script error' and get to the actual error message? maybe there is another approach for global JS error handling, or some webpack-specific hack?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so not really an answer to the debug question, but if anyone runs into a problem with unknown JS error in "Fetch as Google" / "Page speed insights" JS rendering engine - try using Chrome version suggested by user-agent (in my case it was `Chrome/41.0.2272.118`).

When I downloaded an appropriate version of Chromium and opened my site I got a JS error, which was a webpack/jQuery loader conflict. Removing jQuery dependency fixed the site for Google.